# Jackson infinite recursion when deployed on cloudbees

Tags: json, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

I used @JsonManagedReference and @JsonBackReference to solve the problem of infinite recursion and its working fine when I deploy on local tomcat, but when I deploy my application on cloudbees I get the error.
Here are the code fragments:

```
In my Employee class.
@JsonManagedReference("userCollection-securityRoleCollection")
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable( name = "USER_ROLE",joinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "EMPLOYEE_ID",referencedColumnName = "EMPLOYEE_ID" ) },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn( name = "SECURITY_ROLE_ID",referencedColumnName = "SECURITY_ROLE_ID" ) } )
public Set< SecurityRole > getSecurityRoleCollection()
{
    return securityRoleCollection;
}


In my SecurityRole class
@ManyToMany( mappedBy = "securityRoleCollection" )
@JsonBackReference("userCollection-securityRoleCollection")
public List< Employee > getUserCollection()
{
    return userCollection;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? OR How could the platform affect this?
Already spent hours on this but nothing doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the Jackson version to 2.2.3 from 1.9.0 and it just worked fine.